# JavaScript converting long date to short date

Tags: javascript

I have the (german) Output: `Fri Sep 09 2022 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`
and I would like to have just the **yyyy-mm-dd** date: `2022-09-09`

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date's are not too great in JS, the reason that  libs like moment.js etc are very popular.

But one idea is to simply replace the GMT+0300 to GMT+0000, and then parse into Date object and use ToISOString and slice the first 10 chars.

eg.

```js
function shortDate(dt) {
  return new Date(dt.replace(/GMT\+..../,'GMT+0000')).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
}

console.log(shortDate('Fri Sep 09 2022 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and competently answer! I will migrate it to my Programm soon! :)

Comment: @TommyTwo if this is the correct answer, you should marked is accepted.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze sorry, I'm new to this! ;)